# How can i delete all labels from my frame without deleting the frame itself?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive tried to accomplish this by appending each Label into a list.

```
for tasks in range(0, num_tasks):
    stat = 'IDLE'
    active_labels.append(
        Label(page2, text=rr, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=ys_adi1,
                                                                                        y=ys_adi3))
    rr = rr + 1
    active_labels.append(
        Label(page2, text=rr, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=ys_adi2,
                                                                                        y=ys_adi4))

    active_labels.append(
        Label(page2, text=page_name1, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=name1,
                                                                                                y=name3))
    active_labels.append(
        Label(page2, text=page_name2, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=name2,
                                                                                                y=name4))

    active_labels.append(
        Label(page2, text=proxy_address, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=mm,
                                                                                                   y=mn))
    Label(page2, text=proxy_address, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=mm,
                                                                                               y=mna)

    status_label1 = Label(page2, text=stat, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(
        x=stat1, y=status_in1)
    active_labels.append(status_label1)

    status_label2 = Label(page2, text=stat, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(
        x=stat2, y=status_in2)
    active_labels.append(status_label2)
```

And using a for loop to loop through the list and .delete() each one.

```
for label in active_labels:
    Label.destroy(label)
```

This sadly doesnt work and im once again stuck on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in what you're saving to `active_labels`. If you examine it, you'll see it's nothing but a list of `None` values. That is because `Label(...).place(...)` always returns `None`.

The first step is to separate widget creation and widget layout, so that your `active_labels` list accurately contains all of the labels. Then, you can delete them in your loop by calling `destroy` on each label:

```
for label in active_labels:
    label.destroy()
```

The other solution is to not worry about maintaining a list. Any widget can return a list of its children, so you can simply loop over that list:

```
for label in page2.winfo_children():
    label.destroy()
```

Note: this assumes that you're actually putting the labels in `page2`, and haven't made the same mistake and `page2` is set to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `winfo_children()` on the `frame` widget you have and then destroy each of the `child` widget.

**Here is an example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in range(10):
    tk.Label(frame, text=f'Label {i}').grid(row=i, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

The above code will make `10` label widgets inside of `frame`

[image: 10 labels]

Now, use the `winfo_children()` on this `frame` to get each `child label widget` and destroy each of them and then see chnages in the GUI

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in range(10):
    tk.Label(frame, text=f'Label {i}').grid(row=i, column=0)

# get the children widget and destroy them
for label in frame.winfo_children():
    label.destroy()

window.mainloop()
```

This will destroy all the `label` widgets inside of `frame` and return an `empty` GUI like this

[image: empty gui]